# How to build Qt4 with Visual Studio 2015 without official support?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, qt4

I want to use `C++11` and `C++14`, so I downloaded `VS2015` and used it to build my `Qt4` program.

Before that I built the `Qt4` library with `VS2015`. Then I built my program in debug mode and I found an error. It occurs here:

```
QList<QNetworkInterface> lis = QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces();
```

I think maybe the libraries I built generate the error?

**Error message**

[image: Heap corruption error]

Comment: qt source code:https://github.com/qtproject/qt

Comment: if you have time,please help me build the qt souce code,i try every method that i can, for example,i do as:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848962/how-to-build-qt-4-8-6-with-visual-studio-2015-without-official-support,my configure :configure -debug-and-release -opensource -shared -fast -qt-sql-sqlite -qt-sql-odbc -qt-libpng -qt-libmng -qt-libjpeg -platform win32-msvc2015

Comment: In C++ a heap corruption usually is caused by incorrect handling of a pointers. For example using a pointer after it was freed, or write beyond the allocated memory.

Comment: As @Ismael points out, most probably you're looking for the problem in the wrong place. Try debugging your application code.

Comment: i have resolved it