# C1xx: fatal error C1083 because of spaces in file path (while building Qt 4.8 for MS VS)

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build Qt 4.8.6 for MS Visual Studio 2015 following [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32848999/6901388) by trig-ger. On the stage #5 (configure) I've got multiple errors `c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file", related to spaces in file path`D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0`:

```
Files
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: Files: No such file or directory
Microsoft
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: (x86)\Microsoft: No such file or directory
Visual
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: Visual: No such file or directory
Studio
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: Studio: No such file or directory
include
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 14.0\VC\include: No such file or directory
Files
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: Files: No such file or directory
Microsoft
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: (x86)\Microsoft: No such file or directory
Visual
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: Visual: No such file or directory
Studio
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: Studio: No such file or directory
QtCore
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 14.0\VC\include\QtCore: No such file or directory
Files
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: Files: No such file or directory
Microsoft
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: (x86)\Microsoft: No such file or directory
Visual
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: Visual: No such file or directory
Studio
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: Studio: No such file or directory
global
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 14.0\VC\src\corelib\global: No such file or directory
Files
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: Files: No such file or directory
Microsoft
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: (x86)\Microsoft: No such file or directory
Visual
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: Visual: No such file or directory
Studio
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: Studio: No such file or directory
xml
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 14.0\VC\src\corelib\xml: No such file or directory
```

Here is my configure command:

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC>D:\Soft\Qt\4.8\msvc2015\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6\configure -make nmake -platform win32-msvc2015 -prefix D:\Soft\Qt\4.8\msvc2015 -opensource -confirm-license -opengl desktop -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

Do you have any ideas how I can fix this problem? I don't know if this is a typical Qt's problem with spaces in file path (caused by configure) or error related to Visual Studio (caused by c1xx).

**Upd**. I changed command line root directory to just `D:>` and run `configure` again. It started work at last (`header created for [...]`) but eventually produced another error after `Creating qmake...`. At first I got multiple lines such as:

```
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'SOURCE_PATH', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'SOURCE_PATH' ignored
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type '=', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file '=' ignored
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'D:\Soft\Qt\4.8\msvc2015\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6\src\corelib\xml', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'D:\Soft\Qt\4.8\msvc2015\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6\src\corelib\xml' ignored
```

And finally:

```
SOURCE_PATH
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: SOURCE_PATH: No such file or directory
=
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: =: No such file or directory
include
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: D:\Soft\Qt\4.8\msvc2015\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6\include: No such file or directory
SOURCE_PATH
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: SOURCE_PATH: No such file or directory
=
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: =: No such file or directory
QtCore
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: D:\Soft\Qt\4.8\msvc2015\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6\include\QtCore: No such file or directory
SOURCE_PATH
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: SOURCE_PATH: No such file or directory
=
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: =: No such file or directory
global
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: D:\Soft\Qt\4.8\msvc2015\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6\src\corelib\global: No such file or directory
SOURCE_PATH
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: SOURCE_PATH: No such file or directory
=
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: =: No such file or directory
xml
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: D:\Soft\Qt\4.8\msvc2015\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6\src\corelib\xml: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why are you running configure inside program files? Choose a path on D, without spaces in it (qmake is broken with spaces)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, it's default command line directory for Visual Studio command prompt. I switched to just `D:>` and solved originally problem, but got another one (see my Upd above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by switching command line root directory. Instead of

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC>D:\Soft\Qt\4.8\msvc2015\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6\configure [options]
```

or

```
D:>Soft\Qt\4.8\msvc2015\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6\configure [options]
```

it should be just

```
D:\Soft\Qt\4.8\msvc2015\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6>configure [options]
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it was setting an env var CL to the path of the exe. This is not a great idea.